# Change background color with mouse hover with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this menu with different classes and I want to change the background color with mouseover on men7 and men8

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.men4').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).menu ul ul('background-color', 'yellow');
  });
});
```

```css
.menu ul ul {
  background-color: rgba(128, 255, 255, 0.96);
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="lvl-0">
    <li class="men1">
      <ul class="submenu lvl-1">
        <div class="container ">
          <div class="grid">
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
      <li class="men2">
        <li class="men3">
          <li class="men4">
            <li class="men5">
              <li class="men6">
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm trying with jQuery, but it doesn't work :/

What's wrong?

Comment: `$(this).menu ul ul('background-color', 'yellow');` look at this. What do you think?

Comment: 1) You have no `.men7` and `.men8` elements 2) use css, `.men7:hover, .men8:hover { background-color: yelllow; }`

Comment: sorry, men5 and men6

Comment: All code parts in your question contain big errors. I suggest you to learn basic HTML / JS (no offense, you would just save time).

Comment: it's just an extract.. thx anyway for your suggest

Answer (score 1):

I guess from the context of the question, you required this:

```js
$('.men5, .men6').hover(function() {
    $('.menu ul ul').css('background', 'yellow');
  },
  function() {
    $('.menu ul ul').css('background', 'rgba(128, 255, 255, 0.96)');
  }
);
```

```css
.menu ul ul {
  background-color: rgba(128, 255, 255, 0.96);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="lvl-0">
    <li class="men1">
      <ul class="submenu lvl-1">
        <div class="container ">
          <div class="grid">
            I am going to be Yellow on hover
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
      <li class="men2"></li>
      <li class="men3"></li>
      <li class="men4"></li>
      <li class="men5">Hover me for Yellow</li>
      <li class="men6">Hover me for Yellow</li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.men7 .men8').hover(function(){
            $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
        });
    });
```

If you want the proper way to do it in your css file add:

```
.men7 .men8:hover { background-color: yellow; }
```

Comment: thx for answer, but the hover is on submenu not on menu5

Comment: @Armando if you want the hover on <ul class="submenu lvl-1"> then change the selectors to .submenu

Answer (score 0):

Main mistake is (as Tushar said) in your jquery mysterious ".menu ul ul" thing... You just have to use .css with jquery to change css attributes of elements.

Here is what's wrong :

```
$(this).menu ul ul('background-color', 'yellow');
```

Change it with :

```
$(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

Now : Your code is changing the background color ONCE and only once. It keeps the yellow background once you passed your mouse over it...

check this :

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.men4').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });
});
```

HTML :

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul class="lvl-0">
        <li class="men1">
            <ul class="submenu lvl-1">
                <div class="container ">
                    <div class="grid">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="men2">menu2</li>
        <li class="men3">menu3</li>
        <li class="men4">menu4</li>
        <li class="men5">menu5</li>
        <li class="men6">menu6</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS :

```
.menu ul ul {  
    background-color:rgba(128, 255, 255, 0.96);
    display:inline-flex;
    width:100%;  
}
```

Here is a fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/jsuqf5w6/5/

EDIT :

If you want to change css on something else than the target, just switch selector :

```
$('.men4').mouseover(function(){
    $('.submenu').css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

I don't understand why... but here is what you want, another fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/jsuqf5w6/7/

Hope it helps!

Comment: thx, but i want to change the background on submenu ul ul not in men5,

Comment: so when im going on hover menu 5 i want to change background on submenu ul ul, it's different

Comment: ok, in your code you say menu4, so i coded for menu 4. Now check my edit, is this what you want?

Comment: yes in your jsfiddle work, but not in my own code, i don't understand why :/

Comment: All this code when css :hover would do everything.

Comment: @Armando Adapt your code with the fiddle code then!! ^^